# What measures should I take to protect private user information when using the GET method in an Android application with SSL?

Tags: android, security, ssl, url, getmethod

Is using GET method to communication secure inside android application?

I am a novice programmer. I have a question about the security of user information on the server side, in Android programming. In some parts of my work, I have used GET method to send and receive information. In this method, I have sent a variable by URL to the server, and the user's information is sent to the client. Since this information is private, I want them to be safe and not accessible by others.
Thank you in advance.